# Does radius affect performance of geo queries in geofire-common in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

```js
// Find cities within 50km of London
const center = [51.5074, 0.1278];
const radiusInM = 50 * 1000;

// Each item in 'bounds' represents a startAt/endAt pair. We have to issue
// a separate query for each pair. There can be up to 9 pairs of bounds
// depending on overlap, but in most cases there are 4.
const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, radiusInM);
const promises = [];
for (const b of bounds) {
  const q = query(
    collection(db, 'cities'),
    orderBy('geohash'),
    startAt(b[0]),
    endAt(b[1]));

  promises.push(getDocs(q));
}
```

Does the radius affect the performance of geo query? (The code example is taken from firebase docs). I am particularly interested in performance assocaited it with locating documents, not transfering them to client. Because I am thinking about doing these operation on firebase function and then transfer only three or five documents to client. So in short, Does locating documents also take more time when I increase radius? Because I read somewhere the firebase query takes same time without depending on db size. Also, do you think, tranfering the fetching part to firebase function increases performance?

Comment: What do you mean?  Of course, if you increase the radius, and it captures more documents as a result of covering more area, then it's going to take more time to pull them all down to the client.  If you have a specific concern about the radius, I suggest editing the question to explain what that is.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for your comment. I have added more details.

Comment: Even if you only transfer a limited number of documents to the client, the query still has to fetch all the matching documents from Firestore, and that still costs time and money.  Increasing the radius can **only** ever get more documents, which means the performance still goes down.  Do you have a concern beyond these facts?

Comment: @DougStevenson Does locating documents also take more time when I increase radius? Because I read somewhere the firebase query takes same time without depending on db size. Also, do you think, tranfering the fetching part to firebase function increases performance?

Comment: If that's your question, please edit the post to be clear what you're asking so that others who see this later understand what the issue is.  Important information should not be buried in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore has a pretty simple but unique performance guarantee: the performs of any query depends on the number (and size) of the results that are returned, and not on the number of documents it needs to consider.

So if the larger region leads to Firestore having to return more documents, it will be slower than with a query that returns fewer documents. But the region size itself has no impact on it.

In other words, if you have a query on the same collection for a 10m radius that returns 100 documents will take just as long as a query with a 1000m radius that returns 100 documents from that collection.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. Also, what do you think about transferring this fetching logic to Firebase function and returning less no of documents by sorting closest cities( or whatever) and filtering false positions(geofire-common limitation)?

Comment: That's a valid approach to reduce the number of documents that the client needs to receive (because you can eliminate the false positives that are inherent to geohash based filtering), but it makes no difference on the actual query that is sent to the database. You'd also lose the ability to use a realtime listener from the client with this approach. You will have to decide whether this trade-off is worth it for your use-case.